# Maxtor 500gb Hard Drive is not being detected

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-detection

I have two computers and one of them is running on Windows 7. I have two hard drives which are used by First computer. My other pc does not have hard drive. so, I removed an additional storage hard drive (Maxtor 500gb 7h500f0) from my first computer and installed it in another computer without an OS but it was not detected by it.

Then, I removed it and installed in my first pc then it works superb.

First PC Configuration:

- Intel Quad core cpu
- OS - Windows 7

Second PC Configuration:

- Dual core amd 64bit cpu.

My question is "Why Maxtor 500gb hard drive is detected by only one computer ?"

Comment: Is it a Pata (ide) or Sata hard drive?

Comment: It is a Sata hard drive. My hard drive's Brand and Model is Maxtor 7h500f0 500gb Hard Drive

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Run window by either going to the Start Menu and selecting Run or pressing WindowsKey + R.
2. Type `diskmgmt.msc` and hit Enter.
3. Select "Yes" if User Access Control asks for administrative access.
4. Disk Management should open up. Here you should be able to see all the drives connected to your Windows machine.
5. Look for any drives without a letter assigned to it, right-click and assign a drive letter.

*Note: if there are partitions in this hard drive, there might be more than one unassigned "drive", so repeat the process if needed.*

If the hard drive is - as you claim - fully functional, this should allow Windows Explorer to show the hard drive in My Computer. However if it fails to work, considering it's from an old PC, it's most likely to be corrupted. Try formatting the hard drive from Disk Management.

Comment: Second pc does not have os. I can access it in my first pc.

Comment: Ah, right. You should mention that *specifically* in the question in order to avoid the confusion. Open the BIOS settings in the second computer and see if it detects the hard drive. Considering this was the secondary hard drive, it doesn't have any boot files on it - which is why the computer isn't detecting the hard drive.

Comment: It was not detected by bios in my second PC

Comment: Connect the hard drive to the first PC, **back up the necessary files** and format the drive. Then try connecting it to second system and see if the BIOS recognises it.

Comment: There could be only a few reasons why your BIOS might not detect the drive:

1. It isn't enabled in the BIOS
2. The SATA drivers aren't installed properly
3. The data cable is unplugged/faulty
4. The jumper settings on the drive is incorrect

Please troubleshoot these and respond.

Comment: I have tried Seagate 160 GB it works fine in my second pc but Maxtor 500 GB is not detected by second system bios